# How can I overwrite a System.Drawing.Bitmap onto an existing GDI bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi

If I have a .Net `Bitmap`, I can create from it a GDI bitmap by calling the `Bitmap`'s `GetHbitmap()` method.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
IntPtr gdiBmp = bmp.GetHbitmap();
```

This works fine, but every time you call `GetHbitmap`, Windows has to allocate the new memory that the returned `IntPtr` references.

What I'd like to do - if possible - is write a function (I know PInvoke will be necessary here) that also generates a GDI bitmap copy of a `Bitmap`, but that overwrites an existing chunk of memory already referenced by an `IntPtr` returned from `GetHbitmap` instead of allocating new memory.  So it would look something like this (if it were an extension method of `Bitmap`):

```
// desired method signature:
void OverwriteHbitmap(IntPtr gdi)
{

}

// ex:
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
IntPtr gdi1 = bmp1.GetHbitmap();

Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
bmp2.OverwriteHbitmap(gdi1); // gdi1 is still pointing to the same block
    // of memory, which now contains the pixel data from bmp2
```

How can I do this?  I assume I'll need to know the structure of a GDI bitmap, and probably I can use `LockBits` and `BitmapData` for this, but I'm not sure exactly how.

**Clues for the bounty hunters:**

`Bitmap` has a method `LockBits` which locks the bitmap in memory and returns a `BitmapData` object.  The `BitmapData` object has a `Scan0` property which is an `IntPtr` pointing to the start of the locked bitmap's pixel data (i.e it *doesn't* point to the bitmap's header a.k.a. the start of the bitmap itself).

I'm pretty sure the solution looks something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
IntPtr gdi1 = bmp1.GetHbitmap(); // now we have a pointer to a 
    // 100x100 GDI bitmap

Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
BitmapData data = bmp2.LockBits();
IntPtr gdi1Data = gdi1 + 68; // magic number = whatever the size 
    // of a GDI bitmap header is
CopyMemory(data.Scan0, gdi1Data, 40000);
```

The solution does not have to be generic - it only needs to work for bitmaps with pixel format `Format32bppArgb` (the default GDI+ format).

Comment: Who on earth would downvote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Graphics from the IntPtr with Graphics.FromHdc and use Graphics.DrawImage to paste the Bitmap into it.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid - this is an easy and obvious (in retrospect) way to do this. It's a tiny bit more work than this, since the IntPtr is a bitmap handle rather than a device context, so it has to be selected into the DC with `SelectObject`. At least it still needs a *little* PInvoke to make me happy. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered your own question: use LockBits.

See
[How to: Use LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms229672(v=vs.100))
and
[Bob Powell - Locking Bits](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

I used this method to rapidly draw fractals in a .NET (1.1!) program that I was writing for fun. Of all the methods that I experimented with, this was by far the fastest.

Comment: Well, my basic problem is that the BitmapData.Scan0 member points to the start of the bitmap data in a GDI+ bitmap, whereas the IntPtr from Bitmap.GetHbitmap points to the start of the whole GDI bitmap structure (i.e. it points to the *header*). I just need to know how to figure out the offset from the header to the start of the data.

Comment: Scan0 and the IntPtr from GetHbitmap are both pointers that can be passed to RtlMoveMemory (aka CopyMemory), so that part isn't really that hard.

Answer (score 2):

You should not assume that a HANDLE or HBITMAP is a pointer to anything.  It can be implemented as an index into a handle table, key of a hash table, etc.

However, if you call the GDI [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904(VS.85).aspx) function, the resultant [BITMAP structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183371(v=VS.85).aspx) contains a pointer to the real bits.

Not sure if it would be as fast (I think in the case of the same pixel format for source and destination it will), but [SetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162973(v=VS.85).aspx) should do exactly what you want (replace the data in an existing HBITMAP).

Comment: It sounds like SetDIBits would do exactly what I need, if I knew how to use it from C#, which I don't. :)

Comment: `Bitmap.GetHbitmap` is actually extremely fast, so I wouldn't mind at all if `Bitmap.OverwriteHbitmap` were slower. I'm trying to avoid the memory churn that comes from calling GetHbitmap at a high frequency.

Comment: Actually, I guess GetObject and the BITMAP structure look like exactly what I want. I would use GetObject to get the pointer to a structure that contains the pointer to the GDI bitmap's data and use it as the destination in CopyMemory, along with my bitmapdata's Scan0 as the source?

Comment: Yes.  Or call SetDIBits and pass Scan0 as the last parameter, it will verify that the formats are the same and then do CopyMemory for you.  For help calling these functions from C#, search for them on the pinvoke.net website

Comment: Man, you want the 100 just for telling me to go to pinvoke.net? I *knew* I should have made the bounty bigger.

Comment: The `BITMAPINFO` structure required by `SetDIBits` is also exactly the same as the `BitmapData` structure you get from `LockBits`, so it's mostly a matter of just copying fields from one to the other.  Or, if you're sure that the pixel formats are identical, go the `GetObject`/`CopyMemory` route.  And from your question it sounded like you were already familiar with p/invoke...  If you have a sample project I'll try to integrate the SetDIBits part and troubleshoot it for you, but the code in the question doesn't come close to being a complete compilable application.